# Solution of Laplace Equation with Asymptotic Boundary Condition

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

Is there an explicit solution to the Laplace equation

$\Delta f(x,y,z) =0$

given an asymptotic boundary condition that $f \rightarrow 0$ as $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2} \rightarrow \infty$?

Edit: Such a solution is given by $f(x,y,z) = 1/\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}$.

Comment: Any solution of Maxwell's Equations for a static, bounded charge distribution should do it. That includes the solution you mention.

Comment: Are all of these solutions axisymmetric generally?

Comment: Not in general. I think only when the theta derivative of the distribution is zero.